# What are the major ancient literature on Judaic mysticism and spiritual development?

Tags: history, books-generally, internet, translation, mysticism-kabbalah

What are the major ancient literature on Judaic mysticism and spiritual development? By ancient I mean B.C.E.

I also would appreciate if you can also provide links to online English translations if it is possible.

Comment: Are you also interested in later works of kabbala?

Comment: @H' Gabriel, not in this question. I asked this to be to compare it with early Christian mysticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The books you are looking for are called "Merkavah" and "Heichalot" literature.  These are based on the "Merkava" (Chariot) described in Ezekiel.

The earliest work is the Sepher Yetirah, however none of these works are actually from BCE. Sepher Yetirah likely comes from the 1st century, and Heichalot literature from the 7th century.

The earliest mystical writings in Judaism of course though belong to specific passages of Tanach.  (the saphire brick work mentioned in the passages of the 10 commandments, the Seraphim and angles of Bereshit and the Prophets etc.)

Some quick links I found from wikipeida..

http://www.tabick.abel.co.uk/heichalot.html

http://www.digital-brilliance.com/contributed/Karr/HekRab/index.php

http://www.digital-brilliance.com/contributed/Karr/Biblios/mmhie.pdf

Link to the text of Sepher Yetrirah in English here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/yetzirah.htm
http://www.psyche.com/psyche/txt/kaplan_sy_short.html
While a link to Aryeh Kaplan's translation plus commentary and context is here:  [http://www.amazon.com/Sefer-Yetzirah-Creation-Aryeh-Kaplan/dp/0877288550](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0877288550)

Comment: See wikipedia for example about the dating.  Neither Heichalos nor Sefer Yetzira necessarily date from that period.

Comment: "saphire brick work mentioned in the passages of the 10 commandments"?

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few in Hebrew:

- [Sever Yetzira](http://hebrewbooks.org/50625) - Avraham Avinu
- [Heichalos](http://hebrewbooks.org/41146) - [R' Yishmoel Kohen Gadol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishmael_ben_Elisha_ha-Kohen)
- [Zohar](http://hebrewbooks.org/44307) and [Tikkunei Zohar](http://hebrewbooks.org/20445) - [Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi_Shimon_Bar_Yochai)
- [Bahir](http://hebrewbooks.org/31510) - R' Nechunia ben Hakaneh
- [Raziel Hamalach](http://hebrewbooks.org/35003) - Adam Harishon, though [many](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=28050&pgnum=26) dispute this attribution.

Comment: The Ramak says that Sefer Yetzira was written by Rabbi Akiva, and it's impossible for Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai to have written all of the Zohar, since it mentions rabbis who lived hundreds of years after he did.  And it is known that the Zohar was actually composed by Moshe ben Shemtov D'leon. Which sections are from Rabbi Shimon bar yochai and which parts are not, is not known. So putting him as the author is just not correct.

Comment: @avi: many people greater than me have discussed these issues and have explanations for them. For example, about the later rabbis mentioned in the Zohar: some say that these were their future souls discussing these matters in Gan Eden. (Or, more simply, they might well be otherwise unrecorded namesakes of later scholars; there are thousands of sages throughout the generations whose names are unknown even though there is evidence that they existed.) It's certainly incorrect to say dogmatically that "it is known" that R. Moshe composed the Zohar, when there are well-known arguments against that.

Comment: Nobody denies that R. Moshe composed the Zohar...  Just because someone has an explanation doesn't mean it's true.  Otherwise I have some silver bracelets to sell you...

Comment: @avi *Nobody* is an extreme phrase. Most in the Chareidi world (and in the general Jewish world since the time of the Rishonim until recently) believed that R' Shimon Bar Yochai wrote the Zohar.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I don't deny that many people think that R' Shimon Bar Yochai wrote the Zohar.  However, Nobody denies that R' Moshe -compiled- it.  To put this another way. There is a machlochet regarding R. Shimon.  There is NO machlochet regarding R. Moshe.

Comment: Maybe I should word this another way...  Would anybody accept the statement that Moshe wrote the Talmud?  But there are those who say that all Torah Shbal peh comes from Sinai!  Ah, but we know that Rav Ashi and Ravina compiled the Talmud, even if everything once came from Moshe.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I should have read your link first :)  to quote:  Those who believe, in accordance with Jewish tradition, that the Zohar is indeed an authentic document of the teachings of Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai (Rashbi), generally agree that part, but not all, of the Zohar was written by Rashbi. T

Answer (score 3):

The Dead Sea Scrolls prove that the Jewish mystical tradition of divine union went back to the first, perhaps even the third century B.C.E. Jewish mysticism has its origins in Greek mysticism, a system of belief which included reincarnation. Among the Dead Sea Scrolls, some of the hymns found are similar to the  Hekhaloth hymns of the Jewish mystics. One text of hymns gives us clear evidence of Jewish mysticism. The text is called "Songs of the Sabbath Sacrifice." Fragments of  1 Enoch, which is considered the oldest text of Jewish mysticism, were also found with the Scrolls. Since evidence shows Jewish mysticism existed in the third century B.C.E., as Enoch indicates, then it would certainly have existed in first-century Israel.

Quote from: [Jewish Afterlife Beliefs](http://www.near-death.com/experiences/judaism06.html)

Comment: Just incase people follow your link and read more... Today, the dead sea scrolls are NOT associated with Josephus's Esecenes.  http://www.amazon.com/Qumran-Context-Reassessing-Archaeological-Evidence/dp/1565636120