# How long did the Second Temple stand?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash

The classic Jewish sources (Seder Olam, accepted and cited Bavli in several locations; for example, see the discussion on Avoda Zara 9a) state that Bayis Sheini (the Second Temple) stood for 420 years.  I have a vague recollection that other (accepted!) Jewish sources give other numbers, but I cannot remember which sources or what numbers they give.  Can anyone help out?

Please note I am asking for specifically (traditional) Jewish sources.  I know many secular historians like the number 586; that's not what I'm looking for.

**Update:** Although I accepted @Joelk's answer, this question (like many that may be asked on *Mi Yodea*) can have more than one valid answer; specifically, other numbers cited by other sources.

Comment: Can you edit to define "accepted" and "Jewish sources"? What if I find you a rabbi who agrees with the "secular historians"? Motion to close as unclear.

Comment: @DoubleAA How would you word it? "Jewish sources" rather than "secular sources", even if the author of the secular source happens to be Jewish. I would not think examples are needed, but I would accept any alternate view cited in Bavli, Yerushalmi, or a Midrash. Or a view stated by one of the Geonim, Rishonim, or Acharonim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76477/discussion-between-menachem-and-double-aa).

Comment: [Rabbi Ishmael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi_Ishmael) spoke of roughly [700 years](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14917) spanning from the destruction of [Solomon's Temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon's_Temple) at the beginning of the [Babylonian captivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_captivity) to the [destruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE)) of the [Second Temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Temple) in 70 CE, in the middle of the [Jewish-Roman War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish-Roman_War) (66-73 CE).

Comment: A more in-depth explanation can be found [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/106735/1).

Comment: @Lucian It's taking a bit of research to understand your point, but offhand, I have two comments: 1) You seem to consistently link to revisions rather than questions and answers.  Unless you have a specific reason for this, I find it slightly irritating. 2) R' Yishmael reckoning "34 years for Media" is the crux of the discrepancy: my understanding is that the secular reckoning suggests that number ought to be 200.  (They end with Alexander's rise to power.)

Comment: @Menachem: Certain aspects of the traditional Jewish reckoning do indeed seem to somewhat contradict the chronologies of all other nations involved in the events in question, while other aspects, on the other hand, seem to blend in perfectly with them. So, before prematurely jumping to any simplistic conclusions, take the time to acquaint yourself to the various somewhat self-contradictory historical aspects present within the traditional Jewish reckoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Don Yitzchak Abravanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Abarbanel) in his [Haggadah Zevach Pesach](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/abrabanel-p/abrabanel-p04.pdf) on the passage of Baruch Shomer Havtachato (page 2 in the linked pdf) writes:

   > ועמד הבית השני בבנינו תכ"ה שנה
   >
   > And the Second Temple stood built for 425 years.
2. [Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) writes in his [commentary to chapter 7 of the book of Daniel](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nli/Hebrew/library/Pages/BookReader.aspx?pid=425555) (page 325 in the linked scanned copy):

   > ובית שני עמד ארבע מאות ושבע ושלושים שנה וחצי
   >
   > And the Second Temple stood for 437 and a half years.
3. [R. Azariah dei Rossi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azariah_dei_Rossi) writes in [Me'or Einayim, Imrei Binah chapter 36](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20254&st=&pgnum=319) that, apart from these two sources, he found very few who argued explicitly on Chazal's chronology.

   However, he does infer that [R. Yehudah HaLevi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Halevi) and [R. Eshtori HaParchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishtori_Haparchi) necessarily hold of a period longer than 420 years.

   They both write that the Anshei Knesset HaGedolah only started 40 years after the building of the Second Temple. Shimon HaTzaddik is said to have been  active at the end of the period of the Anshei Knesset HaGedolah, and was present when Alexander the Great conquered Judea from the Persians, which took place 380 years (or possibly 386 years) before the destruction of the Second Temple. Thus, if these Rishonim held that the Second Temple lasted for only 420 years, there would be no time during which the Anshei Knesset HaGedolah were active (because 40 + 380 = 420).

Comment: +1 The vast majority of Rishonim not only would have had little to no reason to doubt Chazal's number, they wouldn't have had much basis for proposing any alternative. They weren't exactly avid readers of early Greek/Persian historical texts, if they even had access to them

Comment: @DoubleAA. Sure. Although note Ba'al HaMaor to Rif Rosh HaShanah 1a where he disagrees with Chazal's identification of Darius and Artaxerxes. This would seem to imply that there were more than the 34 years allotted by Seder Olam for the period between the building of Bayit Sheni and Alexander's conquest.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with that source, but while there can be lots of places where people disagree with a specific point, they don't generally develop whole alternate consistent chronologies. (Which makes it seem like they didn't view the whole chronology as that significant or sacred but just one opinion as a baseline, or else they'd struggle to compensate somewhere else.)